# puppet looking for hiera.yaml in the wrong place

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I want puppet to look for hiera.yaml in /etc but it's looking for it in /etc/puppet. I put a line into puppet.conf:

```
hiera_config = /etc/hiera.yaml
```

But still gives me the hiera.yaml update warning when I run the script.

I'm running the script from Vagrant 1.2.2. Using puppet 3.2.2

I'm running Centos 6.4 in a vm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... On Vagrant 1.2.2 and Puppet 3.2.3, I am able to set hiera_config in puppet.conf without problems. I would double-check that you are editing /etc/puppet.conf on the Vagrant vm, not on the host machine, and that the hiera_config line is the [main] block, not just in the [master] block.

If both of those conditions are true and it is still not working, you might try explicitly setting hiera_config in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  ...
  puppet.options = '--hiera_config=/etc/hiera.yaml'
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: I was updating my puppet.conf under the /vagrant directory not the one under /etc/puppet/puppet.conf. I would expect it to copy it over when puppet is run instead of having to make it part of the box image. Is there any way to guarantee this?

Comment: I just went ahead and added it to puppet options. Seems to work great so far. Thanks! I still am curious if there's a way to copy the puppet.conf from the /vagrant file to /etc/puppet/

Answer (score 8):

I found that the puppet provisioner in vagrant now support `hiera_config_path` which does exactly what is desired.

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  # path on host machine to hiera.yaml
  puppet.hiera_config_path = '/Users/me/vms/hiera/hiera.yaml'
  # This sets the relative path for hiera data directories
  puppet.working_directory = '/Users/me/vms/hiera'
end
```

This is documented in [Vagrant: Up and Running](http://books.google.com/books?id=7rJqqKCvdagC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=Vagrantfile+hiera_config_path) but I didn't find it until I started looking into the vagrant source to implement this feature myself.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet provisioning runs as *root* user, not *vagrant*, so that's why it doesn't take notice of your puppet.conf in /vagrant.

If you run `puppet config print` inside the vm from user vagrant and root you see ALL puppet config settings per user and compare.